# comparing rows of a logical matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have sentences cross words [4 cross 5] matrix as follows:

```
out=

0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 1
```

I want to create a 1D cell array based upon above matrix which should tell in which two sentences same words appear with `value = 1` i.e. let's take `line 1` and `line 2` in which at 2 points `column 2` and `column 3` the logical matrix has both `1's` in `row 1` and `row 2` this information should be stored in 1D cell array.

suppose above example it's output would be as:

```
output{1,1} = []
output{1,2} = [2 3]
output{1,3} = [3]
.....
output{n,n} = [....]
```

where `{1,1}` tells `sentence 1` relation with `sentence 1` on the basis of `value=1` of words, `{1,2}` tells `sentence 1` relation with `sentence 2` on the basis of `value=1` of words and so on...

Comment: Why is `output{1,3} = [1]`? Shouldn't it be `[3]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo sorry that's my bad, i did a mistake - thanks for pointing it out. question corrected

Comment: And shouldn't `output{1,1}` be `[2 3 5]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes u are rite actually i was not interested with its self relation that's why ignored it but thank you for pointing this point as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = [ 0 1 1 0 1
      1 1 1 0 0
      0 0 1 1 0
      1 1 0 1 1];
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:size(x,1));
y = arrayfun(@(m,n) find(x(m,:) & x(n,:)), ii, jj, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Result:

```
y{1,1} =
     2     3     5
y{2,1} =
     2     3
y{3,1} =
     3
y{4,1} =
     2     5
[...]
```

If you want the diagonal elements to be empty:

```
y = arrayfun(@(m,n) find(x(m,:) & x(n,:) & m~=n), ii, jj, 'uniformoutput', 0)
```

Result:

```
y{1,1} =
     []
y{2,1} =
     2     3
y{3,1} =
     3
y{4,1} =
     2     5
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want something written quick... and since we are dealing with cell arrays, the easiest thing would be to have a pair of `for` loops.  Assuming that you have your matrix defined in `out`:

```
out_cell = cell(size(out,1),size(out,1));
for idx = 1 : size(out,1)
    for idx2 = 1 : idx
        vals = find(out(idx,:) & out(idx2,:));
        out_cell{idx,idx2} = vals;
        out_cell{idx2,idx} = vals;
    end
end
```

For each pair of rows, `idx` and `idx2`, we look to see if any columns match in terms of having a 1, then place the indices into its respective cell location in the 2D cell array.  Note that because will encounter pairs of rows that are duplicates (i.e. checking row 3 and row 5, compared to row 5 and row 3), there is no need for the second `for` loop to iterate all over the other rows.  We only need to check up to the current row that is described by the outer loop and we simply write the same values with the row indices swapped... so this is a "symmetric" matrix.

If you would like the diagonal elements to be empty, simply change the inner `for` loop so that it goes `for idx2 = 1 : idx-1`, instead of `for idx2 = 1 : idx`.

With your example, we get:

```
>> out_cell

out_cell = 

    [1x3 double]    [1x2 double]    [         3]    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]    [1x3 double]    [         3]    [1x2 double]
    [         3]    [         3]    [1x2 double]    [         4]
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [         4]    [1x4 double]

>> celldisp(out_cell)

out_cell{1,1} =

     2     3     5



out_cell{2,1} =

     2     3



out_cell{3,1} =

     3



out_cell{4,1} =

     2     5



out_cell{1,2} =

     2     3



out_cell{2,2} =

     1     2     3



out_cell{3,2} =

     3



out_cell{4,2} =

     1     2



out_cell{1,3} =

     3



out_cell{2,3} =

     3



out_cell{3,3} =

     3     4



out_cell{4,3} =

     4



out_cell{1,4} =

     2     5



out_cell{2,4} =

     1     2



out_cell{3,4} =

     4



out_cell{4,4} =

     1     2     4     5
```

Comment: Exploiting the fact that you use loops, you could avoid computing each pair twice: `for idx2 = 1 : idx` (or `for idx2 = 1 : idx-1`), and within the inner loop fill `out_cell{idx2,idx}` as well

Comment: Also, I think the OP only wants ones. So `==` becomes `&`

Comment: @LuisMendo - Correct as well.  Fixed.  I forgot that this would be a "symmetric" matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks alot for your detailed answer with step by step description, it worked perfectly fine.